# Regex for matching format like Number Letter, Number Number Letter, Number Number Number Letter

Tags: javascript, regex

I need regular expression for validation which would accept only three combinations from input (Number and letter - > 1A or Number + Number + Letter -> 15A or Number + Number + Number + Letter -> 115A)

Comment: It couldn't be more localized.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the following regex take a group of digit between 1 and 3 **\d{1,3}** following by one letter **\w{1}** and seems match your need

```
(\d{1,3}[a-zA-Z])
```

Comment: You can do : - `s/\w{1}/\w/g`

Comment: @boulatin I think `\w` will match numbers, as well.

Comment: Can add anchors, too `^\d{1,3}[a-zA-Z]$`

Comment: Thank you very much, it helped me to solve my problem. My validation is now working fine :)

Answer (score 0):

You can try such expression #[0-9]+[A-Za-z]{1}# or #[0-9]{1,3}[A-Za-z]{1}#

Comment: [0-9]+ allows one or **more** digits which will allow more than 3 digits.